# Clickonce ONLY using ftp

Tags: .net, clickonce

When I try to publish, the update asks me for http url. Is there anyway to publish via Clickonce doing updates but only specify FTP and not HTTP link?
Also, I only have read permission for FTP.

Is this possible or I would need more data?

Comment: FTP is a URL.  Did you just try ftp://... for the URL?

Comment: any final solution with sample source code ?